# Daemon python wrapper "subprocess I/O timed out", need some directions

Tags: python, daemon, tex

I am not very familiar with the way of creating a daemon in Python, therefore wheb trying to install and run a third party open source TeX Python Wrapper i got bite by an error i do nor really understand.

I added some print to help debugging.

The faulty one is called texdp.py

When i run mathrand which calls texdp server start,
i get the following error

```
output_fds  {8: 'dvi', 5: 'log', 6: 'logfile', 7: 'err'}
input_fds  3
readable, writable [] [3]  outflds, inputflds:  [8, 5, 6, 7] [3]
pointer len_str:  0 63
folder fd:  7
readable, writable [5] []  outflds, inputflds:  [8, 5, 6, 7] []
pointer len_str:  63 63
folder fd:  7
readable, writable [5] []  outflds, inputflds:  [8, 5, 6, 7] []
pointer len_str:  63 63
folder fd:  5
readable, writable [] []  outflds, inputflds:  [8, 5, 6, 7] []
pointer len_str:  63 63
folder fd:  5
SUB IO ERROR: readable []  pointer == len_str: 63 , 63

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mathtrand", line 18, in <module>
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mathtran/server.py", line 71, in start
    self.secplain.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tex/texdp.py", line 159, in start
    self.process(self._params.start)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tex/texdp.py", line 175, in process
    value = self._process(str + self._params.done, self._params.done_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tex/texdp.py", line 210, in _process
    raise SubprocessError, 'subprocess I/O timed out'
```

The part of the code responsible is attached and located around line 200 in the method **def _process**.

I have no idea of where to start looking, and what does this error really means.
Any help is more than welcome.

https://texd.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/texd/trunk/py/tex/texdp.py

```
# Copyright: (c) 2007 The Open University, Milton Keynes, UK
# License: GPL version 2 or (at your option) any later version.
# Author: Jonathan Fine <jfine@pytex.org>, <J.Fine@open.ac.uk>

"""Wrapper around TeX process, to handle input and output.

Further comments to go here.
"""

__version__ = '$Revision: 116 $'[11:-2]
# $Source$

# TODO:  Move interface instances to elsewhere.
# TODO:  error recovery, e.g. undefined control sequence.
# TODO:  Abnormal exit is leaving orphaned processes.
# TODO:  Refactor _process into tex.util, share with metapostdp.

import os                               # Create directories and fifos
from select import select               # Helps handle i/o to TeX process
from tex.util import make_nonblocking   # For non-blocking file descriptor
from tex.util import DaemonSubprocess
from tex.dviopcode import FNT_DEF1, FNT_DEF4
import signal


class SubprocessError(EnvironmentError):

    pass

# TODO:  This belongs elsewhere.
class Interface(object):
    """Stores useful, but format specific, constants."""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # TODO:  Be more specific about the parameters.
        self.__dict__ = kwargs


# TeX knows about these fonts, but Python does not yet know.
# This list created by command: $tex --ini '&plain' \\dump
preloaded_fonts = ( 'cmr10', 'cmr9', 'cmr8', 'cmr7', 'cmr6', 'cmr5',
                    'cmmi10', 'cmmi9', 'cmmi8', 'cmmi7', 'cmmi6',
                    'cmmi5', 'cmsy10', 'cmsy9', 'cmsy8', 'cmsy7',
                    'cmsy6', 'cmsy5', 'cmex10', 'cmss10', 'cmssq8',
                    'cmssi10', 'cmssqi8', 'cmbx10', 'cmbx9', 'cmbx8',
                    'cmbx7', 'cmbx6', 'cmbx5', 'cmtt10', 'cmtt9',
                    'cmtt8', 'cmsltt10', 'cmsl10', 'cmsl9', 'cmsl8',
                    'cmti10', 'cmti9', 'cmti8', 'cmti7', 'cmu10',
                    'cmmib10', 'cmbsy10', 'cmcsc10', 'cmssbx10',
                    'cmdunh10', 'cmr7 scaled 2074',
                    'cmtt10 scaled 1440', 'cmssbx10 scaled 1440',
                    'manfnt', )

# Ship out a page that starts with a font def.
load_font_template = \
r'''%%
\begingroup
  \hoffset 0sp
  \voffset 0sp
  \setbox0\hbox{\font\tmp %s\relax\tmp M}%%
  \ht0 0sp
  \shipout\box 0
\endgroup
'''

secplain_load_font_template = \
r'''%%
\_begingroup
  \_hoffset 0sp
  \_voffset 0sp
  \_setbox0\_hbox{\_font\_tmp %s\_relax\_tmp M}%%
  \_ht0 0sp
  \_shipout\_box 0
\_endgroup
'''


plain = Interface(format='plain',
                  start = r'\shipout\hbox{}' '\n',
                  done = '\n' r'\immediate\write16{DONE}\read-1to\temp ' '\n',
                  done_str = 'DONE\n',
                  stop = '\end' '\n',
                  preloaded_fonts = preloaded_fonts,
                  load_font_template = load_font_template,
                  )

secplain = Interface(format='secplain',
                  start = r'\_shipout\_hbox{}' '\n',
                  done = '\n' r'\_immediate\_write16{DONE}\_read-1to\_temp ' '\n',
                  done_str = 'DONE\n',
                  stop = '\_end' '\n',
                  preloaded_fonts = preloaded_fonts,
                  load_font_template = secplain_load_font_template,
                  )



class Texdp(DaemonSubprocess):
    """Wrapper around TeX process that handles input and output.

    More comments go here.    
    """

    _fifos = ('texput.tex', 'texput.log', 'texput.dvi')

    def _make_args(self):

        # Don Knuth created plain.fmt, renamed by some to tex.fmt.
        fmt = self._params.format
        if fmt == 'plain' or fmt == 'tex':
            fmt = ''
        else:
            fmt = '--fmt=' + fmt

        # Build up the arguments list.
        args = ('tex', '--ipc',)
        args += ('--output-comment=""',) # Don't record time of run.
        if fmt:
            args += (fmt,)
        args += ('texput.tex',)
        return args

    def start(self):

        super(Texdp, self).start()      # Start the TeX process.

        # We will now initialise TeX, and conprocessnect to file descriptors.
        # We need to do some low-level input/output, in order to
        # manage long input strings.  Therefore, we use file
        # descriptors rather than file objects.

        # We map output fds to what will be a dictionary key.
        ofd = self._output_fd_dict = {}

        cwd = self._cwd                 # Shorthand.
        child = self._child 

        # For us, stdin and stdout are special.
        self._stdin = child.stdin.fileno()
        self._stdout = child.stdout.fileno()

        # Read stdout and stderr to 'log' and 'err' respectively.
        ofd[self._stdout] = 'log'
        ofd[child.stderr.fileno()] = 'err'

        # Open 'texput.tex', and block until it is available, which is
        # when TeX has started.  Then make 'texput.tex' non-blocking,
        # in case of a long write.
        self._texin = os.open(os.path.join(cwd, 'texput.tex'), os.O_WRONLY)
        make_nonblocking(self._texin)

        # Read 'texput.log' and 'texput.dvi' to 'logfile' and 'dvi'.
        for src, tgt in (('texput.log', 'logfile'), ('texput.dvi', 'dvi')):
            fd = os.open(os.path.join(cwd, src),
                         os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
            ofd[fd] = tgt

        # Ship out blank page, and initialise preloaded fonts.
        self.process(self._params.start)
        self._fontdefs = []
        for font_spec in self._params.preloaded_fonts:
            self.load_new_font(font_spec)

    def process(self, str):
        "Return dictionary with log, dvi, logfile and err entries."

        # TeX will read the data, following by the 'done' command.
        # The 'done' command will cause TeX to write the 'done_str',
        # which signals the end of the process.  It will also pause
        # TeX for input.

        # TODO: I do not know why the pause is required, but it is.
        # Remove it here and in the _params, and the program hangs.

        value = self._process(str + self._params.done, self._params.done_str)
        self._child.stdin.write('\n')   # TeX is paused for input.
        return value

    def _process(self, str, done_str):

        # Write str, and read output, until we are done.  Then gather
        # up the accumulated output, and return as a dictionary.  The
        # input string might be long.  Later, we might allow writing to
        # stdin, in response to errors.

        # Initialisation.
        print "output_fds ", self._output_fd_dict
        output_fds = self._output_fd_dict.keys()
        print "input_fds ", self._texin
        input_fds = [self._texin]

        accumulator = {}
        for fd in output_fds:
            accumulator[fd] = []

        pointer, len_str = 0, len(str)

        # The main input/ouput loop.
        # TOD0: magic number, timeout.
        done = False
        while not done:
            readable, writable = select(output_fds, input_fds, [], 0.1)[0:2]
            print "readable, writable", readable, writable, " outflds, inputflds: ", output_fds, input_fds
            print "pointer len_str: ", pointer, len_str
            print "folder fd: ", fd
            if not readable and pointer == len_str:
                print "SUB IO ERROR: readable", readable, " pointer == len_str:", pointer, ",", len_str
                os.kill(self._child.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
                self._child.wait()
                raise SubprocessError, 'subprocess I/O timed out'

            if pointer != len_str and writable:
                written = os.write(self._texin, str[pointer:pointer+4096])
                pointer += written
                if pointer == len_str:
                    input_fds = []

            for fd in readable:
                if self._child.poll() is not None:
                    raise SubprocessError, 'read from terminated subprocess'

                tmp = os.read(fd, 4096)
                if fd == self._stdout:
                    if tmp.endswith(done_str):
                        tmp = tmp[:-len(done_str)]
                        done = True
                accumulator[fd].append(tmp)

        if pointer != len_str:
            raise SystemError, "TeX said 'done' before end of input."

        # Join accumulated output, create and return ouput dictionary.
        value = {}
        for fd, name in self._output_fd_dict.items():
            value[name] = ''.join(accumulator[fd])
        return value

    def load_new_font(self, font_spec):
        """Tell both TeX and Python about a new font.

        Raises an exception if the font is not new.
        """

        # Ask TeX to load font, and ship out page that uses it.
        command mathtran= self._params.load_font_template % font_spec
        dvi = self.process(command)['dvi']

        bytes = dvi[45:-1]                  # Page body.
        opcode = ord(bytes[0])              # First opcode.

        # The first opcode should be a fontdef, which we extract.
        if FNT_DEF1 <= opcode <= FNT_DEF4:
            body_len = (2 + (opcode - FNT_DEF1)
                        + 12                # Checksum, scale, design size.
                        + 2)                # Length of 'area' and font name.

            name_len = ord(bytes[body_len - 2]) \
                       + ord(bytes[body_len - 1])

            fontdef = bytes[:body_len + name_len]
            self._fontdefs.append(fontdef)
            return

        else:
            raise ValueError, "font '%s' not new or not found" % font_spec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is based on the `select` call

```
readable, writable = select(output_fds, input_fds, [], 0.1)[0:2]
```

The timeout is 0.1 seconds.  Is this appropriate?

The variable names are murky ("pointer" makes little sense in Python).  However, it appears that if nothing happens on 0.1 seconds, a "timeout" is raised.

---

Weirdly, this program opens files to communicate with a subprocess.  That's very odd to be "sharing" a file with a subprocess.

Usually we do one of two things -- use pipes to communicate actively with a subprocess or use files to leave the subprocess run on its own.

Here's a simpler design.

1. Put the input into the input file.
2. Run the Tex daemon subprocess until it finishes or you're tired of waiting for it.
3. If you're tired of waiting for it, kill it.

   Else

   - Look at the status from the wait function
   - Read the output file.

That's pretty much all you need.  And there will be no mysterious "pause", no low-level I/O, no non-blocking I/O.

If, for some reason you need to communicate with the subprocess, then you should look at  replacing the files with pipes (which aren't shared and are probably a better for for whatever you're doing.)

Comment: When i try to play with the timeout even at 3s i still get the error.

Comment: I will try your way, (its now that i regret no taking OS class in CS).

Comment: The simplest thing (spawn a subprocess) is what the shell does; there's a lot of good things to be said about simplicity.